# Can I move 1U hardware into a tower chassis?

Tags: conversion, chassis

I wish to setup a home web server.

I bought a 'Dell PowerEdge 1850 Server' but as it's in a 1U case, the fans are small, and make far to much noise (for home use).  (like Concord taking off!)

So I considered just buying a used "standard" PC, or building a new one, but I'm concerned about reliability (being on 24/7).

The Dell seems well made, and seems to have many advantages, including twin Xeon processors, but if I had a hardware failure, then a standard PC formate would be easier, quicker and probably cheaper (for me) to fix.

Then I wondered if I could make the Dell much quieter by converting it to fit a standard sized (tower) case, and using much larger fans at slower speeds?

Would that be possible ?

Comment: Some background knowledge: Almost all 1U servers are very noisy (almost, my Dell R300 seems to be an unexpected happy exception). This is mostly due to the small fans running at high speed. If you want less noise, get a model (desktop or server) with larger fans.

Comment: Part of what makes servers reliable is the interaction between the computer and the chassis (so it knows about fan speeds, PSU conditions, drive enclosure states, etc.), that way it can alert you about physical conditions.  Changing to a 'no-name' chassis will cause you to lose a lot of those features, and in turn a lot of the server's 'reliability'.

Comment: The easy answer: Yes you can migrate the hardware to a tower PC. But the difficulty is pretty much as the answer below has pointed out. Those 1U rack server are meant to be away from you, locked away in a cooled room. If you are planning to use them on your side / table, you better have a good earphone. To add to @Hennes comment, even if you get a bigger fan, bigger case, there are no guarantee it won't be as noisy if your home server is very hammered with activity (or if you run lots of other applications on it). Note2: Some RACK motherboard does not fit on TOWER case, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can move the parts into a standard sized case and use larger fans at lower RPMs. I don't have any experience with the `Dell PowerEdge Server` systems, so I don't know if the motherboard will be standard spec i.e. if it will fit inside a standard case without having to modify the case.

From what I know, the Dell server motherboards use a proprietary layout, thus restricting your potential choice of case. If the motherboard does have a proprietary layout and you're willing and able to modify a case to accommodate the motherboard, moving the remainder of the parts should not be a problem.

Once you have moved the parts across you can use larger and quieter fans. Having said that, the motherboard may not have as many fan headers as you need, which means that you would need to buy an external fan controller of some kind for any additional fans. Some cases come with a built-in fan controller so this may not be an issue at all.

[Fractal](http://www.fractal-design.com/) do some pretty good cases that are optimized for silence and would be perfect for a Server type build. The `Fractal Design R4` is an example of one such case.